# Calculate difference based on group and by row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Table is broken down by two factors from 'group' column: Customer and Customer Support.

I would like to calculate the ratio between each given the month and total fields.

Reference table df (only goes to April but full table goes all the way to Dec):

```
Group            | Month  | Total

Customer           Jan       170
Customer Support   Jan       141
Customer           Feb       134
Customer Support   Feb       131
Customer           Mar       162
Customer Support   Mar       136
Customer           Apr       236
Customer Support   Apr       190
```

What I would like is to create a new field that shows the response ratio between Customer Support (numerator) to Customer (denominator). So a row calculation but from the bottom up.

Desired output:

```
Group            | Month  | Total | Response Ratio

Customer           Jan       170    0.82
Customer Support   Jan       141    0.82
Customer           Feb       134    0.97
Customer Support   Feb       131    0.97
Customer           Mar       162    0.83
Customer Support   Mar       136    0.83
Customer           Apr       236    0.8
Customer Support   Apr       190    0.8
```

This will then allow me to calculate the 'Global avg response ratio' across all the data.

Comment: please provide your sample data in a ready-to-use format, e.g. with `dput()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'Month' and divide the values assuming the first element is 'Customer per 'Group'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Month) %>%
    mutate(ResponseRatio = Total/first(Total), ResponseRatio = replace(ResponseRatio, 1, ResponseRatio[2])) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  Group            Month Total ResponseRatio
  <chr>            <chr> <int>         <dbl>
1 Customer         Jan     170         0.829
2 Customer Support Jan     141         0.829
3 Customer         Feb     134         0.978
4 Customer Support Feb     131         0.978
5 Customer         Mar     162         0.840
6 Customer Support Mar     136         0.840
7 Customer         Apr     236         0.805
8 Customer Support Apr     190         0.805
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("Customer", "Customer Support", "Customer", 
"Customer Support", "Customer", "Customer Support", "Customer", 
"Customer Support"), Month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Apr", "Apr"), Total = c(170L, 141L, 134L, 131L, 162L, 
136L, 236L, 190L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pivot wider

```
data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = Total) %>%
mutate(`Response Ratio`=Customer/`Customer Support`)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is with a `pivot_wider()` and then `mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- tribble(~Group, ~Month, ~Total,
              "Customer", "Jan", 170,
              "Customer Support","Jan", 141)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Group",
              values_from = "Total") %>%
  mutate(ratio = `Customer Support`/Customer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Month) %>%
    mutate(Response_Ratio = sum(Total) / max(Total) - 1)
```

```
 Group            Month Total Response_Ratio
  <chr>            <chr> <int>          <dbl>
1 Customer         Jan     170          0.829
2 Customer Support Jan     141          0.829
3 Customer         Feb     134          0.978
4 Customer Support Feb     131          0.978
5 Customer         Mar     162          0.840
6 Customer Support Mar     136          0.840
7 Customer         Apr     236          0.805
8 Customer Support Apr     190          0.805
>
```